# Vector as a result of the autocorrelation function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm struggling with the implementation of the autocorrelation function. I know how to calculate total result of the autocorrelation for a given vector shifted by a given value. But I don't know how can I return result as a "full" vector, i.e autocorrelation function. This is my code:

```
'''
Calculate the autocorrelation coefficient.
'''

import numpy as np

Xi = np.array([1, 2, 3])
N = np.size(Xi)
k = 2
Xs = np.average(Xi)

def autocovariance(Xi, N, k, Xs):
    autoCov = 0
    for i in np.arange(0, N-k):
        autoCov += ((Xi[i+k])-Xs)*(Xi[i]-Xs)
    return (1/(N-1))*autoCov

def autocorrelation():
    return autocovariance(Xi, N, k, Xs) / autocovariance(Xi, N, 0, Xs)

print("Autocorrelation:", autocorrelation())
```

...and now I want it to return a vector `[-0.5  0.   1.   0.  -0.5]`. I can't figure out what I'm missing. I've implemented above function according to the autocorrelation equations for discrete signal, i.e:

[image]

...and after normalization...

[image]

What should I do, to allow my script to return a result as a vector of autocorrelation function?

PS Of course I know `numpy.correlate()`, but I want to write various implementations of autocorrelation function by myself, to know how it actually works.

Comment: Have you considered using numpy.correlate, or do you want to write the correlation yourself?  http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.correlate.html

Comment: Of course I know `numpy.correlate()`, but I want to write various implementations of autocorrelation function by myself to know how it actually works.

Comment: If there's an obvious solution that you're not using, it helps to say so in the question so that others (who obviously have no idea about what you do and don't know) can figure out what it is you need.

Comment: My question refers to the implementation of autocorrelation function as such. I did not ask about the existing method, or functionality. It does not require a lot of mental effort to see it in the question, and realize that I'm lacking of few steps from given `input` to the functions' pre-described `output`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem solved. What I did, was to calculate the autocorrelation coefficient for each `k` value from the range of `<|-k|;k>` where `k` belongs to `N+ sum {0}`. And that's it.